# How does $0$ being an identity element of naturally ordered semigroup follow from its definition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, semigroups

In the context of naturally ordered semigroups, $0$ is defined as the semigroup's smallest element (in other words, ${\forall}x\,{\in}\,S:0\,{\preceq}\,x$ where $ S$ is our semigroup).

Natural numbers under addition are a naturally ordered semigroup. The source I'm using says that $0$ being the indentity element of $\mathbb{\ N}$ stems from the definition of $0$. How?

Comment: I don't see that it would.  Isn't $\mathbb Z^+$ (Integers greater or equal to 1) a semi-group.  Then $0 = 1$ in this semi-group by definition, but the semigroup doesn't have an identity element.  So I'm as confused as you are.

Comment: @fleablood, This is not true for ordered semigroups in general (as you've pointed out).  The 'naturally' in 'naturally ordered semigroup' actually packs a lot of hidden meaning.  (See Nex's answer below for full list of axioms)  The intent behind the 'naturally ordered semigroup' axioms is to define the structure of the natural numbers under addition.  As such extra axioms are needed to get us from the 'ordered semigroup' structure to the structure of natural numbers.

Comment: Ah. I wasn't certain what the term "naturally ordered semigroup" definition was, and I didn't realize well ordering and axiom 6 were required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us agree what a naturally ordered semigroup is first. A **naturally ordered semigroup** is a triple $(X,+,\leq)$  where $X$ is a set $+$ is a binary operation and $\leq$ is a relation such that:

1. $(X,+)$ is a commutative semigroup (i.e $+$ is commutative and associative);
2. $(X,\leq)$ is a preorder (i.e $\leq$ is reflexive, transitive and anti-symmetric);
3. For all $x,y,z \in X$, we have $x \leq y \Rightarrow x+z \leq y +z$;
4. For all $(X,\leq)$ is well ordered;
5. For all $x,y,z\in X$, we have $x+z=y+z \Rightarrow x=y$;
6. For all $x,y \in X$, we have $x \leq y \Rightarrow $ there exists $w$ such that w+x=y$;

Suppose $X$ is not empty.
Since $(X,\leq)$ is well ordered it has a least element $0$. We will prove that $0$ is the identity element of $(X,+)$. Since $0 \leq 0$ it follows by (6) that there exists $w$ such that $0+w=0$. However $0 \leq w$ and hence (by (3)) $0+0 \leq 0+w=0$. This means that $0+0=0$ (since $0\leq 0+0$ and $\leq$ is anti-symmetric). Next since $0 \leq x$ it follows by (6) that there exists $u$ such that $u+0=x$, and so we have $x +0=(u+0)+0=u+(0+0)=u+0=x$ as required.

Comment: Are you sure about the existence of axiom $3.$? Here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Naturally_Ordered_Semigroup/Axioms there is written nothing about it.